# Unable to render bot framework prompt in slack using interactive messages

Tags: typescript, botframework, slack-api

I am trying to use Slack's interactive messages to post a slack block kit JSON for a section and buttons. However i am getting an error that says Invalid ChannelData

I tried posting the block JSON through the slack api tester and it works but not through the code I wrote. I wrote some custom code to override the prompt function in bot framework specifically for the slack channel.

Overrided prompt

```
   public async prompt(stepContext: WaterfallStepContext, dialogId: string, options: PromptOptions): Promise<DialogTurnResult> {

        let promptText: string = '';
        if (isString(options.prompt)) {
            promptText = options.prompt;
        } else if (isActivity(options.prompt)) {
            promptText = options.prompt.text;
        }
        this.logger.log(`prompt: ${promptText}`);

        const choices = options.choices.map((choice) => {
            let text = '';
            this.logger.log(`choice: ${choice}`);
            if (isString(choice)) {
                text = choice;
            } else if (isChoice(choice)) {
                text = choice.value;
            }
            // return { name: text, type: 'button', text: text, value: text };
            return {
                type: 'button',
                text: {
                    type: "plain_text",
                    text: text
                },
                value: text
            };
        });

        const channelData = {
            text: '',
            blocks: [
                {
                    type: "section",
                    text:
                        {
                            type: "mrkdwn",
                            text: "Are you using a Mac or PC?"
                        }
                },
                {
                    type: "actions",
                    elements: choices
                }]
        };
        this.logger.log(`channelData: ${JSON.stringify(channelData)}`);

        return await stepContext.prompt('ChoicePrompt', { type: ActivityTypes.Message, channelData: channelData });
    }
```

helper functions:

```
function isString(str: any): str is string {
    return typeof str === 'string';
}

function isActivity(obj: any): obj is Activity {
    return obj && obj.text !== undefined;
}

function isChoice(obj: any): obj is Choice {
    return obj && obj.value !== undefined;
}
```

Called with:

```
const channel = getChannel(step.context);
        return await channel.prompt(step, 'ChoicePrompt', {
            choices: buttons,
            prompt: this.generateAssetInfoMessage(deviceType),
            retryPrompt: `Sorry, I didn't understand. Please choose one of the following:`,
        });
```

I expect to see a message with the two buttons but i'm getting an error saying 
*[onTurnError]: Error: Invalid ChannelData*
Here is the channel data stringifyied

```
{"text":"","blocks":[{"type":"section","text":{"type":"mrkdwn","text":"Are you using a Mac or PC?"}},{"type":"actions","elements":[{"type":"button","text":{"type":"plain_text","text":"I'm using a Mac"},"value":"I'm using a Mac"},{"type":"button","text":{"type":"plain_text","text":"I'm using Windows"},"value":"I'm using Windows"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you aren't doing anything wrong. We just don't support that, yet.

I've submitted a [Design Change Request](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5434) so that we can map the payload from `channelData` to the appropriate Slack API. <strike>It's nothing you can do, locally, either, since this relies on the private/secure part of the API.</strike>

Note, however, that once this is implemented, you'll likely add it to your message's `channelData` like this:

```
"channelData": {
   "text": "Now back in stock! :tada:",
   "blocks": [
        [...]
   ]
```

**Edit:** You *could* do this locally, but it would be difficult as you couldn't do it directly with the Bot Framework. You'd have to use [Slack's Conversation API](https://api.slack.com/docs/conversations-api) inside of your bot. It's possible and you'd have all of the data you'd need except you'd need a new auth token.

Comment: I'm currently trying out using the slack adapter as a workaround so hopefully that will work. Testing it out. I'm sure you have a process for everything but just asking... What's the design change ETA look like?